# How to compute custom loss for tensorflow using numpy/sklearn based on the predictions

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, scikit-learn, loss

I'me facing an issue to combine numpy with tensorflow. For instance, I want to create a custom loss function and use it for the training.

let loss function be

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(C * tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=self.y_logits, labels=self.y10))
```

where `C` is some value computed based on the following code:

```
def C(logits, y_true, kmeans):    # kmeans is sklearn model
    yp = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    yp_cont = tf.reduce_sum(yp*kmeans.cluster_centers_.flatten(),axis=1)
    yp_discreat = kmeans.predict(yp_cont)    ## this is where I'm having the problem

    ### the rest of the code ###
```

The problem is that I can't use a tensor variable with `kmeans` sklearn model. Is there some work around to overcome this issue?

Comment: (Without much practical TF experience): you have to use TFs graph-language to formulate this. Now this highly depends on the function itself, which is incomplete. Now it's not that easy to do that for kmeans i think. The problem is smoothness. You seem to want kmean-preds as component in your function, but this one is highly non-smooth which has to be tackled. While checking the distance to centers is an easy convex opt-problem, some classification-like if center0, center1, etc. selected (while others not) is highly non-smooth. I'm sceptical of theoretical feasibility (even with sub-gradients)

Comment: Long story / comment short: (1) Without the complete function it's hard to recommend something. (2) You will want a formulation as smooth as possible. Instead of kmeans.predict, which returns some similar to some one-hot encoding, you probably want some smooth proxy like norm(center, x) for all centers -> some softmax like op. Somewhat a soft-classification approach (probs instead of one-hot; you might squash it further with some exp-like op). (3) Don't expect code from me. I'm not much into TF. Maybe someone else is.

Comment: I think I got your point! I computed the cluster idx from the kmeans model by just taking the min distance from the centroids instead of using the `predict` function, and it now works properly! However, creating a custom loss (for future consideration) with numpy still a problem and this fix doesn't seem to be helping with that!